# Grunt task not found

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a little problem with Grunt.
I have grunt-cli v0.1.9 installed globally and grunt v0.4.1 installed locally

Here is my simple Gruntfile.js :

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('hello', 'My test task.', function() {
        grunt.log.writeln('Hello world');
    });
}
```

However, when I launch :

```
grunt hello
```

I have the following message :

> Warning: Task "hello" not found. Use --force to continue.

Can somebody tell me what is the problem?

Comment: This works for me - you must have something else going on in your environment.  How are you running it? (i.e.: current working directory and where is gruntfile.js located in relation - same directory?)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have npm installed, I suggest to try the following:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify
```